# Can't add files to project in VC6

Tags: visual-c++

I click Project->Add to Project->Files in VC6, and nothing happens. I'm on Win7. I tried running VC6 as administrator, but that didn't help. This happens for even in a newly created project. It's not fatal because I can edit the .dsp file in notepad to add files but it's very annoying.